# Positioning new editors side by side

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, swt, eclipse-rcp

I'm working on an eclipse rcp application and want to avoid this effect when opening a new editor: 
http://www.fotos-hochladen.net/stackededitorsfcpt3zoq.png

and want to achieve this effect programmatically:
http://www.fotos-hochladen.net/separareeditorsmv58nzua.png

Has anyone an idea how this can be achieved?

Thanks! :-)

Comment: Even if the editor pages are created tabbed within the same view, the tab can be dragged outside that view to form it's own separate editor view in the perspective. 

If you really need to achieve this as the default visualization of a new editor then I'm not sure how to do that, but I suggest looking into creating a new view instance and then an editor inside that view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, it is possible, I did it once. Just take a look at the following example:
http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/6277
As I remember, the code will open editors, one on top of the other but the code can be easily adapted so that editors are opened side by side. 
Just post here if it doesn't work and I'll help you with it :)

Oh, I almost forgot... there is no "legal" way to implement your feature so you will have to call "Discouraged access" code.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell from reading the Eclipse Javadoc, your editors will always open as tabs.  It's up to your users to drag and drop one of the editors, so the editors are side by side.

You can submit a request to the Eclipse organization for this feature, if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

This is not available as a default behavior. It is a nice view for those of us with wide enough monitors but Eclipse leaves that choice to the user because most people who are using monitors that are < 22" do not want to see editors side-by-side.